# Include vertical line in ggplot based on value in other column in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse, data-visualization

That's a confusing title but what I have is a df (much larger, but) like this:

```
df
# A tibble: 10 × 3
    week count protest
   <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1  259.       0
 2     2  509.       0
 3     3  556.       0
 4     4  588.       0
 5     5  541.       0
 6     6  576.       1
 7     7  531.       0
 8     8  518.       0
 9     9  470.       1
10    10  392.       1
```

What I want is to plot the line of `count` with `week` in x axis. But I also want to add a vertical line for each `week` that contains value of `protest == 1`.

I've done something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(berlin_week, aes(x=week, y=count)) +
   geom_line() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept= week[match(1, protest)]), col = "red")
```

[image]

But as you see I only get the first observation that has `protest == 1`, not all that have `protest == 1` as I wanted. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Does `geom_vline(xintercept = df$week[df$protest == 1])` not do what you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a red line for any week that has a protest equal to 1, you can use the following code

```
ggplot(berlin_week, aes(x=week, y=count)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = berlin_week$week[berlin_week$protest == 1], color = "red")
```

[image: example1]

Comment: brilliant (and so much simpler than some of the things I was going for). Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help